# How to deal with non-optional values in NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, option-type

To get a value from `NSUserDefaults` I would do something like this:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if let value = userDefaults.objectForKey(key) {
    print(value)
}
```

However, these methods do not return optionals:

- `boolForKey` (defaults to `false` if not set)
- `integerForKey` (defaults to `0` if not set)
- `floatForKey` (defaults to `0.0` if not set)
- `doubleForKey` (defaults to `0.0` if not set)

In my app I want to used the saved value of an integer if it has been previously set. And if it wasn't previously set, I want to use my own default value. The problem is that `0` is a valid integer value for my app, so I have no way of knowing if `0` is a previously saved value or if it is the default unset value.

How would I deal with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register the user defaults in AppDelegate, the best place is `awakeFromNib` or even `init`. You can provide custom default values for every key.

```
 override init()
 {
   let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
   let defaultValues = ["key1" : 12, "key2" : 12.6]
   defaults.register(defaults: defaultValues)
   super.init()
 }
```

Then you can read the values from everywhere always as non-optionals

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
myVariable1 = defaults.integer(forKey: "key1")
myVariable2 = defaults.double(forKey:"key2")
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot that, I changed the post

Comment: I assume that you don't use the hard-coded strings `"key1"` and `"key2"` in production code. Where is the best place to keep a reference to these key names for access throughout the app?

Comment: Either define the keys outside any class as globals or use a static struct for example `struct Key {static let Max = "max" static let Min = "min"}` also outside any class. Then you can use it with `defaults.integerForKey(Key.Max)`. The benefit of the struct is encapsulation of the data

Answer (score 7):

You can use `objectForKey` (which returns an optional) and use `as?` to optionally cast it to an `Int`.

```
if let myInteger = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: key) as? Int {
    print(myInteger)
} else {
    print("no value was set for this key")
}
```

The solutions for `Bool`, `Float`, and `Double` would work the same way.

**Note:**

I recommend going with the accepted answer and setting default values rather than casting a generic object if possible.

Comment: Try this with Swift 4: `(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "unlock_count") as? Int) != nil)`

Answer (score 0):

You could register defaults for your app that aren't legitimate values using [`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults.registerDefaults()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:)

Answer (score 0):

This article describes very well how to "make" them Optional http://radex.io/swift/nsuserdefaults/

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    class Proxy {
        var object: NSObject? {
            return defaults.objectForKey(key) as? NSObject
        }

        var number: NSNumber? {
            return object as? NSNumber
        }

        var int: Int? {
            return number?.integerValue
        }

        var bool: Bool? {
            return number?.boolValue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if var value : Int = userDefaults.objectForKey(key) {
    print(value)
}
```